# Best opensource IDE for building applications on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ide

Looking to dabble with GAE and python, and I'd like to know what are some of the best tools for this - thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would spend the time and learn something like ***emacs***.  The learning curve is a bit higher, but once you get used to it, you can develop from any terminal.  It has fantastic support for python and many other libraries.

You have to remember that Python is a dynamically typed language so the traditional IDE is not really the answer since those are mostly designed for statically typed languages.  Basically you want something that has syntax highlighting, compilation and maybe some shortcuts and macros to make life easier for you... emacs has all of this :)

I would Google "Emacs Python" to get started.

If you really don't want to use emacs, I would look at [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/).  It's an extension to the eclipse IDE that let's you write python code.  Some of my friends that do Django work have had good luck with that one.

Hope this helps.

Good luck with GAE.

Comment: -1 for emacs. Booo! Vim all the way, baby!  (p.s. I didn't really -1, honest.)

Comment: +1: also emacs can have completion, refactoring tools, integrated debugger, etc, all features from any IDE.

Comment: please, real programmers use butterflys.... http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: I really, really like vim. It's similar to emacs, but doesn't have complicated keyboard shortcuts. There is a tutor to help you get started. Just type 'vimtutor' in the terminal.

Comment: There are many traditional IDEs that work perfectly well with Python.

Answer (score 6):

Netbeans has some very nice tools for Python development

Comment: Yes, I just installed NetBeans with the Python plugin the other day, and I'm very impressed by it. I think it still needs some more work, especially in the code-completion, but definitely one of the best free IDEs I've tried.

Comment: This is an old post, so I would just like to note that as of my writing this, there is still *NO* Python support for netbeans 7.0

Answer (score 6):

I use pydev on eclipse, and works well for django too!

Answer (score 2):

VIM(there's enough plug-ins to make it IDE -like)

Komodo IDE($$)

Eclipse w/Pydev

Net Beans with Python support

WingIDE($$)

SPE(Stani's Python Editor)

Answer (score 2):

[Open Komodo](http://www.openkomodo.com/)

Comment: It certainly has some quirks, but I've been rather happy with it's customizability and it's code completion support.  The way it handles Django templates is kinda wonky, but it can be suppressed if it bothers.

Answer (score 0):

I've  been using gedit and am pretty happy with it, there is a couple of good plugins that make life easier (e.g. Class Browser).    I tried eclipse but its just not the same experience you get with Java.

Answer (score 0):

For my recent GAE project I tried both eclipse with pydev and intellij with its python plugin. I use intellij for my "real" work and so I found it to be the most natural and easy to use, personally. It is not open source, but if you already have a license it is no extra cost.

I found the eclipse plugin to be very good as well. You don't get as much intellisense as you would with java, but I was very impressed with what you do get from a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 0):

If your on the Mac I would highly recommend [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).  The IDE is great for coding on projects like Python, PHP, Ruby on Rails, HTML, etc.

The price is $52 US and there is a 30 trial version that you can get to try it out for yourself.  Highly recommended my most Mac Developers.

Also if you watched the [demo's at Google Campfire](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcbpTQXNwac) you'll notice they are using TextMate!

Comment: Is TextMate open source?  Questioner asked for best open source IDE.

Comment: Here it is all about open source IDE so no paid IDE

Answer (score 0):

im using ulipad is fast and simple download [here](http://code.google.com/p/ulipad/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try appengine-emacs-toolkit. http://code.google.com/p/appengine-emacs-toolkit/

This toolkit contains two emacs major mode which help to develop GoogleAppEngine and SinaAppEngine with python.

It provides support for *create new project*, *launch local server*, *open browser to view project*, *upload project*.

This toolkit tested on WindowsXP/7, Ubuntu with GoogleAppEngine-1.6.1, saepythondevguide.