# Which development environment should I use for developing Google App Engine with Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ide

I would like to ask which IDE should I use for developing applications for Google App Engine with Python language?

Is [Eclipse](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/articles/eclipse.html) suitable or is there any other development environment better?

Please give me some advices!
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse with the [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) plugin is very nice. Recent versions even go out of their way to support App Engine, with builtin support for uploading your project, etc without having to use the command line scripts.

See the [Pydev blog](http://pydev.blogspot.com/) for more documentation on the App Engine integration.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers you are looking for are here

[Best opensource IDE for building applications on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495579/best-opensource-ide-for-building-applications-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 2):

I use Komodo Edit; for more information, visit [the website](https://www.activestate.com/products/komodo-edit/).

Comment: I have just found out that even Eclipse with Pydev is not a good one to write code, as sometimes, it does not automatically create tabs and spaces correctly, I had to spend hours to find out why always I have the tab indentation error, thank Ubervan, I moved to Komodo Edit and it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've always been using [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) (with or without plugins to make it more IDE-like) for Python programming, it's simple but powerful enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) is a pretty solid IDE for python.  It's not free though (open source or $$).