# The best tools for working with Google App Engine Python

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, ide

I'm an existing C# (ASP.NET MVC 3 years +), C++, Javascript developer, and have done a bit of Python development in my time.

I'm looking to take on a Google App Engine Python project and essentially I feel a bit lost without a decent integrated IDE experience + Data Management tool with GUI. Is GAE just for hardcore developers that can code right first time, in vim? I feel like I'm wasting time on things that could honestly code in 5 mins in a more Established framework.

I'm currently using the Eclipse plugin, and trying to view all the elements in an array while paused. I'm drilling into objects, but can't seem to find the list.

Is this just something that can't be done with App Engine at the moment, if so please do help me!

I also assume there is no amazing data management tool yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495579/best-opensource-ide-for-building-applications-on-google-app-engine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287606/which-development-environment-should-i-use-for-developing-google-app-engine-with

Comment: Hmm, thinking about it I do write all my JavaScript without those things to help....

Comment: GAE Python is only for hardcore developers that can code using only a magnetized needle and a steady hand :)

Comment: @KevinP - What the heck! Magnetised needle!? Just a knife and a bunch of Hollerith cards!

Answer (score 3):

I have used both [Wing IDE Pro](http://wingware.com/) and [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).  Both are great lightweight IDEs but for me Pycharm is the winner for Google App Engine development.  It has built in support for GAE.

Comment: Currently evaluating PyCharm. Looking good so far! I basically had the same level thing working in Eclipse, but this feels nicer. And it runs GAE in debug out of the box. And I can easily trace my variables/stack etc. Sure you can do it with Eclipse, but this just feels more solid. Also wanted to try out a JetBrains product for a while, so this is a good excuse. The whole thing feels polished.

Answer (score 1):

Get the python plugin for google app engine from http://pydev.org/. It supportS direct deployment to appengine from eclipse. It's one of the best environment for the ones from C#,.NET. It even has autocomplete and lot more........

please refer to this http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/eclipse.html

Comment: I am doing this, the whole startup time seems pretty slow though, at least to walking through in VS..

Answer (score 0):

I use [Wing IDE Pro](http://wingware.com/) and it's the best python ide I've ever used by far. I use VS 2010 Ultimate for C#, so for me to feel comfortable and efficient in Wing says a lot concerning its quality for writing python. For GAE specifically, Wing supports [debugging locally](http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/google-app-engine).